# How to use Formgroup and react Form in angular2 to fix generated textbox problmes

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

I'm using angular2 in my project,i have a service which returns this JSON Object :

> items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}

i tried to populate this JSON object in the UI like this picture shows:
[here's what the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyBgl.png)

heres the code :

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">

<div *ngIf="items?.departure">
    <span>{{items.departure}}</span> --> 
    <span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
        {{items.stations[0].station}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
        {{items.arrival}}
    </span>

    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

    <div *ngIf="!last">
        <span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">{{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
        <div class="input-group spinner">
            <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.stations.length > 0">
    <span>{{items.stations[items.stations.length-1].station}}</span> --> <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button style="margin-left: 479px;"> Submit </button>
```

my problem is when i tried clic (up or down) the spinner to change the value of the textBox, all the textBoxes change its value.can anyone help please to fix this problem ? I tried to use formgroup to fix this issue but i didnt manage to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what's inside you're spinnerPriceUp() and spinnerPriceDown() functions.

You are rendering  textBox from inside of a ngFor loop. 
That is why all the textboxes rendered from this loop are getting 
targeted for the value change.

A way to fix this is by assigning dynamic IDs to you're 
element.

```
  <input [attr.id]="'textbox' + i">
```

'i' being index  &  'textbox' is some text for the ID.

now you have unique ids to your textboxes. Further, you can pass these IDs to the functions performing the update.

Hope this solves you're issue

Comment: thnanks but how can i get the value of textbox?